# Extract huge records from table using JDBC application

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, primary-key, rownum

I have some huge tables on Oracle database (millions of records), I would like to extract all the records with the help of Java JDBC application and store them as a file.
Because of huge records number I would like to partitioned my select query with WHERE statement and extract and store in an iteration manner. (There is INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) during extract data.

What I've tried till now:

- using pagination way with row numbers, which is not completely correct as the query may not cover all the records as the query row numbers may change and therefore query will change.

```
    select * from ( select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */   a.*, ROWNUM rnum 
      from ( your_query_goes_here, 
      with order by ) a 
      where ROWNUM <= 
      :MAX_ROW_TO_FETCH ) where rnum  >= :MIN_ROW_TO_FETCH;
```

see [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-rownum-and-limiting-results)

- Using the primary key for split the records and extract and store data.
  which is not work (at least I think) as what happen if we will have composite primary key or not NUMERIC primary key (for example VARCHAR).

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE PRIMARY_KEY < $MAX_DESIRE AND PRIMARY_KEY <$MIN_DESIRE
```

It is worth to mentioning which duplication of stored records is OK.

Comment: Which problems do you encountered while reading the data in a plain JDBC *single* cursor with an appropriate `fetch size`?

Comment: Your should not use ROWNUM; it is arbitrarily assigned at runtime to your result set and in no way represents a unique key on the data or reflects anything about how the data is stored in the table.